# Counting the # of correctly selected models by a feature selection ML algorithm in its output structured as a df or list

Tags: r, machine-learning, regression, feature-selection, lasso-regression

The datasets and R scripts referred to in this question can all be found in my [GitHub](https://github.com/Spencermstarr/EER-Research-Project) Repository for this project.

The goal is to count how many regression models fitted by a LASSO function in R using the enet function from the elasticnet package on 58k different csv file formatted datasets (all within the same file folder) are correct. Whether a selected model is correct is determined by checking if the included variables in the fitted model for that dataset exactly matches the true underlying regression model for it (it being that dataset). These datasets were generated using a custom Excel macro built in such a way that I know the correct underlying structural model for each dataset (the details are explained in a p.s. section).

I have exported the variables selected by LASSO (when running the code in the 'LASSO code' script) for each dataset to a csv file called 'IVs_Selected_by_LASSO', then re-imported them into a different R script called 'Quantifying LASSO's performance' (and assigned them to an object object called 'BM1_models') after sorting them correctly.

All of the fitted models are stored in the BM1_models object which looks like the following where the n1-n2-n3-n4s before the semicolons represent the names of each csv file and what comes after them are obviously the models selected by the LASSO Regression run on the dataset in that csv file:

```
> BM1_models <- read.csv("IVs_Selected_by_LASSO.csv", header = FALSE)
> head(BM1_models, n = 3)
                    V1
1 0-3-1-1;  X1, X2, X3
2 0-3-1-2;  X1, X2, X3
3 0-3-1-3;  X1, X2, X3

> tail(BM1_models, n = 3)
                                                           V1
57998 1-15-9-498;  X2, X3, X5, X6, X8, X9, X10, X11, X12, X15
57999     1-15-9-499;  X3, X4, X5, X6, X8, X10, X11, X12, X15
58000               1-15-9-500;  X2, X4, X6, X7, X8, X10, X11

> str(BM1_models)
'data.frame':   58000 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ V1: chr  "0-3-1-1;  X1, X2, X3" "0-3-1-2;  X1, X2, X3" "0-3-1-3;  X1, X2, X3" "0-3-1-4;  X1, X2, X3" ...
```

For the record, there are two spaces after each semicolon, not just one.

p.s.
How to tell whether the ML variable/factor selection method (in this case LASSO) is right for any given dataset is if the n2 for that dataset says 3, then the Independent Variables selected should be X1, X2, X3; if it says 4, the underlying structural model is X1, X2, X3, X4, and so on up until X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9, X10, X11, X12, X13, X14, X15 when it says 15. If the selected model is either X1, X3, X4 or X2, X3, X4 when n2 = 3, or any other combination besides X1, X2, X3, this is wrong, it must be exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider nested `strsplit` then `rbind` split vectors into data frame:

```r
BM1_models <- read.csv("IVs_Selected_by_LASSO.csv", header = FALSE)

n_df <- do.call(
  rbind.data.frame,
  lapply(
    strsplit(BM1_models$V1, ";"),
    function(x) {
      s <- strsplit(x, "-")
      c(s[[1]], s[[2]])
    } 
  )
) |> setNames(
  c("n1", "n2", "n3", "n4", "IV")
)

head(n_df)
#   n1 n2 n3 n4           IV
# 1  0  3  1  1   X1, X2, X3
# 2  0  3  1  2   X1, X2, X3
# 3  0  3  1  3   X1, X2, X3
# 4  0  3  1  4   X1, X2, X3
# 5  0  3  1  5   X1, X2, X3
# 6  0  3  1  6   X1, X2, X3

tail(n_df)
#       n1 n2 n3  n4                                                IV
# 57995  1 15  9 495   X2, X3, X4, X5, X7, X9, X10, X11, X12, X13, X15
# 57996  1 15  9 496                     X4, X6, X7, X8, X11, X12, X13
# 57997  1 15  9 497                X2, X3, X4, X9, X10, X11, X13, X14
# 57998  1 15  9 498        X2, X3, X5, X6, X8, X9, X10, X11, X12, X15
# 57999  1 15  9 499            X3, X4, X5, X6, X8, X10, X11, X12, X15
# 58000  1 15  9 500                      X2, X4, X6, X7, X8, X10, X11
```

Then analyze or subset return as needed:

```r
# TABULATE n2 COLUMN
table(n_df$n2)
#   10   11   12   13   14   15    3    4    5    6    7    8    9 
# 4500 4000 4500 4500 4500 4500 4500 4500 4500 4500 4500 4500 4500 

# SUBSET TO NEEDED CRITERIA
sub_n_df <- subset(n_df, n2 == "3")
```

Comment: Wow! This solution is fantastic, thank you very much good sir. All I have to do from here is count up how many are correct. I have tried the following 4 commands, but none have born fruit yet:
count(sub_3_df, sub_3_df$IV == "X1, X2, X3")
count(sub_3_df, when(sub_3_df$IV == "X1, X2, X3"))
CS_3_IV_case <- if (sub_3_df$IV[12] == "X1, X2, X3") { 1 }
CS_3_IV_case <- if (sub_3_df$IV[12] == "X1, X2, X3") { 1 } else { 0 }

I am still a novice with R and don't have much experience using either its if or count functions under my belt yet unfortunately.

Comment: But if you don't have time, from here now that each case is finally neatly separated out, I'm pretty sure that I could easily just write each of the 12 cases into separate csv files, then convert them to Excel Workbooks and use fairly straightforward IF functions returning a 1 when they are correct and a 0 otherwise, then just autosumming at the bottom.

Comment: You could sum the logical for count: `sum(sub_3_df$IV == "X1, X2, X3")`. Or as shown in this answer, run counts across all IV values: `table(sub_3_df$IV)`. Even call `aggregate(cbind(count=n2) ~ IV, sub_3_df, FUN=length)`.

Comment: I totally agree about the sum function proposal except for one minor detail, each individual Logical operation won't work correctly unless I can somehow alter it so that for each dataset & corresponding selected model because without a [num] at the end of sub_3_df$IV, it evaluates whether the entire dataframe is equal to "X1, X2, X3" which is not helpful, obviously.
Here is what I mean concretely, when I run that, this is the top line of the output:
> sub_3_df$IV == "X1, X2, X3"
   [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

Comment: Oh nevermind actually! It appears the problem was stemming from me forgetting to add the two spaces in the "X1, X2, X3" logical condition. It should be "  X1, X2, X3", I'm pretty sure it'll work now, but I'll return if it still doesn't.

Comment: @Partfait thank you again for being so helpful with your answer to this question back in October. But when I just picked back up working on this project will my collaborator, he changed the way you know which regressors are the true regressors from just being known from the name of the dataset to now being specified explicitly in the first two rows of each dataset, newly added rows I might add. So, I need help again now, the new question is here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74935452/how-to-write-a-function-that-scores-how-many-variables-selected-by-lasso-are-cor